# Pylab Piechart display 3 elements

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, charts

3 elements = 3 keys in the dictionary 
2 elements = 2 keys in the dictionary

When trying to display 2 elements everything is working fine .
when trying the same thing with 3 , nothing happens ( picture wont generate)

```
from pylab import *
binNames_tuple = ()
binResult_list  = []
dic = {'7.2': '2', '7.1': '1', '7.3': '3'}
for item in dic:
    #append to tuple  ( labels for the pi chart)
    binNames_tuple = binNames_tuple + (item,)
    #append to list (the results to display )
    binResult_list.append(dic[item])



print binResult_list
print binNames_tuple

mycolors=['#9d1507', '#71c42c','#0099cc']

try :
    figure(1, figsize=(3, 3), dpi=70,)
    ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

    # The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
    fracs = binResult_list
    explode=(0, 0)

    pie(fracs, explode=explode,labels = binNames_tuple , autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,colors=mycolors)
    savefig(('abcd.png'), transparent=True)
    close()
except Exception as e : 
    print str (e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try, except statement fails to raise the assertion error, `assert(len(x)==len(explode))`. In your example, the `explode` column should be the same size as `dict`, e.g.

```
from pylab import *
binNames_tuple = ()
binResult_list  = []
dic = {'7.2': '2', '7.1': '1', '7.3': '3'}
for item in dic:
    #append to tuple  ( labels for the pi chart)
    binNames_tuple = binNames_tuple + (item,)
    #append to list (the results to display )
    binResult_list.append(dic[item])



print binResult_list
print binNames_tuple

mycolors=['#9d1507', '#71c42c','#0099cc']

try :
    figure(1, figsize=(3, 3), dpi=70,)
    ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

    # The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
    fracs = binResult_list
    explode=(0, 0, 0)

    pie(fracs, explode=explode,labels = binNames_tuple , autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,colors=mycolors)
    savefig(('abcd.png'), transparent=True)
    close()
except Exception as e : 
    print str (e)   
    raise
```

Note that this saves the figure abcd.png in the script directory. You should use `plt.show()` if you want the picture to appear.